# How to mange memory used by A-Frame?

Tags: three.js, aframe, webvr, aframe-react

I'm building a web app which has 360 degree images loaded into an a-sky primitive. I'm using `aframe-react`. There are total of 20+ 360 degree images and only one `img` asset inside `a-assets`. once user switches scene react will change `src` of asset `img` and scene will re render. Everything works fine but it's using lot of memory because of caching. One time it used 4GB+ memory. In mobile the web page crashes after switching through ~8+ images. How do I handle this situation?

I tried looking into THREE.Cache but images are not cached there.

Is this memory usage has anything to do with using React?

Answer (score 2):

There's an issue for A-Frame to automatically manage it, but right now have to hack around to clear textures.

```
AFRAME.scenes[0].systems.material.textureCache[url].then(function (texture) {
  texture.dispose();    
});
```

Comment: Wow, thanks. `textureCache[url]` didn't work for me. Used `Object.keys(textureCache)` to iterate and dispose textures. 